# Can you detect return to app from webpage?

Tags: android, flutter

I have looked everywhere I can think of, but have yet to find an answer and nothing seems to react to coming back from a web browser.

Basically, I am trying to log into dropbox via flutter. Majority of the code is written in the native languages, but I need to detect when the app comes back from authentication.

```
  Future<void> _loginDropBox() async {
    String result;
    if (!loggedInBool) {
      try {
        result = await platform.invokeMethod('retrieveAccessToken');
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print("Failed to get token: '${e.message}'.");
      }
      if (result != null) {
        _checkCredentials();
      }
    }
  }
```

Above is what I am using to login, but the issue is that result is null when it reaches _checkCredentials(). Is there a way to wait till result has information and then do _checkCredentials?

Comment: Okay, found the issue with result actually. I would still like to know if it is possible for flutter to detect a return to app process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather unclear what you're asking. Are you asking whether or not we are actually able to find out if a website returned something, or are you asking whether or not Flutter is able to wait for a response?

Perhaps the try block is interfering?

```
  Future<void> _loginDropBox() async {
  String result;
  if (!loggedInBool) {
    try {
      result = await platform.invokeMethod('retrieveAccessToken');
      if (result != null) {
        _checkCredentials();
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get token: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
}
```